# URDF 2 joints in the same link

Tags: urdf

I have been modelling a robot with URDF for a while now and had a problem with my third and fourth joints being in the same position between link_2 and link_3 respectively.

[image]

in my URDF file, I have a relationship between these joints such as the third link changes the orientation of the fourth link in y direction and the fourth link changes the orientation of the third_link in x direction.

```
<!--
<joint name="third_parent_of_fourth" type="continuous">
<parent link="third_link"/>
<child link="fourth_link"/>
<axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
</joint>


<joint name="fourth_parent_of_third" type="continuous">
<parent link="fourth_link"/>
<child link="child_link"/>
<axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
</joint>
-->
```

if I cannot define two joints in the same link, what can I do to achieve the orientation I have described above. I have a Chinese 5 DOF robot that I have bought last year and I am modelling it for my thesis. Any help would be appreciated.